# Two frameworks with the same symbol

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, frameworks, duplicates

I have two frameworks in my Xcode project that both define a class with the same name (B.framework and C.framework both have a class named MyClass), resulting in a couple warnings like so:

```
Duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_MyClass originally in B.framework/B(MyClass.o) now lazily loaded from C.framework/C(MyClass.o)
Duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_MyClass originally in B.framework/B(MyClass.o) now lazily loaded from C.framework/C(MyClass.o)
```

Then at run time only one of the implementations is loaded, and trying to use the other one will result in a "unrecognized selector sent to instance" because they are totally different classes (even though they have the same name).

I use one of the MyClass implementations directly in my code, but the other framework only uses its MyClass internally <del>and I have no idea why its even exported</del> (its not even mentioned in the frameworks header files, i used `nm` to view the symbols).

How can I make both frameworks work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no such thing as "exported" classes in Obj-C. Or rather, there's no such thing as "non-exported" classes. This problem is precisely why the use of 2- or 3-letter prefixes on classes is strongly recommended for all Obj-C code. Your only solution (besides not using these frameworks) is to edit one (or both) of the frameworks to change the class name, or if you don't have access to the source, then you need to contact the vendor and ask them to make that change.

Comment: Thats what I feared. I do not have access to either frameworks source or I would have fixed it in the way you've stated. Before hoping the vendor will fix it for me, a friend has suggested what sounds like a plausible solution (though it does feel kind of hacky): Create my own two frameworks, each one linking to one of their frameworks, and then subclass what i need with proper prefixes. Any idea if this will work or will the symbols from their frameworks still be "exported" through the encapsulating framework? Gunna test asap

Comment: Remember, Obj-C is a dynamic runtime language. Anything which is added to the runtime by any linked object file/framework will be exposed to the entire application.

Comment: Yeah I realized that as I was going to start working on it :( Thanks for the help.